# C# Smarty Streets POST request

Tags: c#, post, smartystreets

I'm trying to send a POST to the Smarty Streets API, but the response I'm getting back is a malformed payload. I went through the documentation on the site and I think I have everything formed correctly to send. I even used Fiddler to see what I"m sending and it looks correct but there must be something I"m missing. I'm relatively new programming. So any help would be appreciated.

```
string url = Uri.EscapeUriString("http://api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id=Id&auth-token=token");
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

TestAddress json = new TestAddress();

json.street = "11 Phelan Ave, San Francisco, CA";

string jsoncvt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsoncvt);
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
httpWebRequest.Host = "api.smartystreets.com";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Accept= "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: It may be the problem here is that the API requires an *array* of street inputs (if you're using a JSON payload), whereas this request is only sending a single object.

Answer (score 0):

As was commented by Jonathan Oliver, the SmartyStreets API expected a collection of input candidates. Simply modify the serialized payload to be a collection:

```
string jsoncvt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TestAddress[] {json});
```